# Contar el número de argumentos en una macro variádica

Tags: c++, c++11

Tengo una macro que, partiendo de una serie de identificadores, me genera una clase con una `enum` y un `std::bitset< >` del tamaño necesario para acomodar 1 bit por cada posible valor de la `enum`:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

template< typename... ARGS > constexpr size_t CountVariadicNumber( ARGS... args ) { return sizeof...( args ); }

#define DECLARE_BITMASK( IDENT, ... ) \
  class IDENT { \
  public: \
    enum { __VA_ARGS__ }; \
    std::bitset< CountVariadicNumber( __VA_ARGS__ ) > _bitsValues; \
  public: \
    IDENT( ) = default; \
    IDENT( const IDENT & ) = default; \
  };

DECLARE_BITMASK( Prueba, ALL, SINGLE, SOME )

int main( ) {
  Prueba p;

  std::cout << "Num: " << p._bitsValues.size( ) << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Funciona bien, **pero** no me gusta la necesidad de una función plantilla  `CountVariadicNumbers( )` externa a la clase. *Polucionar* el espacio de nombres para algo de uso exclusivo de la clase ... no me parece *correcto*.

He intentado colocarla dentro de la clase:

```
#define DECLARE_BITMASK( IDENT, ... ) \
  class IDENT { \
  public: \
    enum { __VA_ARGS__ }; \
  private: \
    template< int... VALS > static constexpr size_t CountVariadicNumbers( VALS... vals ) { return sizeof...( vals ); } \
    std::bitset< CountVariadicNumbers( __VA_ARGS__ ) > _bitsValues; \
  public: \
    IDENT( ) = default; \
    IDENT( const IDENT & ) = default; \
  };
```

Pero no le hizo mucha gracia al compilador:

> error: `VALS` is not a type:
>   `template< int... VALS > static constexpr size_t CountVariadicNumbers( VALS... vals ) { return sizeof...( vals ); } \`
>   error: expansion pattern `int` contains no argument packs
>   `template< int... VALS > static constexpr size_t CountVariadicNumbers( VALS... vals ) { return sizeof...( vals ); } \`

¿ Como puedo contar el número de argumentos que recibo en una macro variádica y utilizarlo en mi clase ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Polucionar* el espacio de nombres para algo de uso exclusivo de la clase … no me parece *correcto*.

Puedes hacer el recuento de elementos dentro de la clase ayudado por `std::initializer_list`:

```
#define DECLARE_BITMASK( IDENT, ... ) \
  class IDENT { \
  public: \
    enum { __VA_ARGS__ }; \
    std::bitset< std::initializer_list<int>{ __VA_ARGS__ }.size ( ) > _bitsValues; \
  public: \
    IDENT( ) = default; \
    IDENT( const IDENT & ) = default; \
  };
```

El constructor de `std::initializer_list` es `constexpr` por lo que se evalúa en tiempo de compilación.

---

Si quieres que se quede dentro de la clase, debe formar parte de la clase (propuesta para C++14 o superior):

```
#define DECLARE_BITMASK( IDENT, ... ) \
  class IDENT { \
  public: \
    enum { __VA_ARGS__ }; \
    template< auto ... ARGS > static constexpr auto elements = sizeof...( ARGS ); \
    std::bitset< elements< __VA_ARGS__ > > _bitsValues; \
  public: \
    IDENT( ) = default; \
    IDENT( const IDENT & ) = default; \
  };
```

Hemos creado una variable plantilla que forma parte de la clase y se usa para inicializar el `std::bitset`.